# Differentiation how to find the equation of normal perpendicular to the straight line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A curve has the equation $y=(2x-3)^2$. Find the equation of the normal to the curve that is perpendicular to the straight line $4x-y-5=0$,

I have differentiated the curve’s equation and I got $4(2x-3)$ as the answer. For the gradient of the straight line, I found that to be $4$. As it is perpendicular, the gradient for the normal would be $-\frac{1}{4}$. Is that right? Well, after this, what are the following steps to find the the equation of the normal?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative gives you the slope of the tangent which is perpendicular to the normal - So the tangent must be parallel to the external line - as you correctly determined the tangent must have a slope of 4.

The normal has slope $-\frac14$

and passes through the point $(
a, (2a-3)^2
)$

where $a$ is the solution to $4(2a-3)=4$